# Defining functions for the special keys on a keyboard in Windows 7 / XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I hope I got a simple question right here for you:

I have a new USB Keyboard with some special keys like "Home, Calculator, Browser, Back Forwared, etc.". When i plug it into a PC with Windows 7 it runs without a configuration. 
But here is the problem.. Is there a possible configuration for it? 
It would be nice to use the Calculator Key for another programm for example.

Do you know a standard Windows tool or a freeware tool for this problem?
Do you know the same thing for Windows XP?

Thank you for your help,
Fake4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do, is to install the software (from the CD that bundled with your keyboard)
and then configure and customize all of the multimedia / internet key's as you wish.

If you still looking for 3rd party software, there are several good options:

- [KBDEdit](http://www.kbdedit.com/)
- [RemapKey](http://www.remapkey.com/)
- [KeyCustomizer](http://www.keycustomizer.com/)

*The first one is highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you you two - I downloaded the official supporttool from Fujitsu. 
I really hoped to get and administration mask directly in Windows 7 - but its only some keys in the registry i guess.

So far its okay ! Thanks!

Comment: No problem mate. If your having any problems with it - feel free to ask again!

Answer (score 1):

You might find what you are looking for at the Microsoft Website:

[Download IntelliType / IntelliPoint and etc.](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=mk)